# Moving point on OpenStreetMap route

Tags: openstreetmap, r, map-point

Basically I generate random numbers in R language which are indeed times between bus arrivals.
I need to simulate a moving point(a bus) in OpenStreetMap by using this generated numbers.
I have read that R language communicates very good with OSM but not sure how to realize this goal.
Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to show movement of a point ON an OpenStreetMap (OSM) map? R can indeed display OSM data and generate numbers but this may not be the best way to do the job; what is your final goal, an animated image?